# In Streaming XSSFWorkbook make part of cell content to bold using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying following two sets of code to make part of the cell content bold/italic in streaming XSSFWorkbook that is SXSSFWorkbook. But it is not working. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

The cell content should look like following

This is ***sample*** *content*

```
try (SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook()) {
    SXSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("With Rich Text");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

    XSSFFont fontPlain = (XSSFFont) wb.createFont();

    XSSFFont fontBoldItalic = (XSSFFont) wb.createFont();
    fontBoldItalic.setBold(true);
    fontBoldItalic.setItalic(true);

    XSSFFont fontItalic = (XSSFFont) wb.createFont();
    fontItalic.setItalic(true);

    XSSFRichTextString cell1Value= new XSSFRichTextString();
    cell1Value.append("This is ");
    cell1Value.append("sample ", fontBoldItalic);
    cell1Value.append("content", fontItalic);

    cell.setCellValue(cell1Value);
    wb.write(new FileOutputStream("BoldFile.xlsx"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also following code does the same. The cell content should look like following

Hello **World**

```
try (SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook()) {
    SXSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("With Rich Text");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    
    Font fontBold = wb.createFont();
    fontBold.setBold(true);
    
    String value = "Hello World";
    String subValue = "World";
    
    cell.setCellValue(value);
    RichTextString rts = cell.getRichStringCellValue();
    rts.applyFont(value.indexOf(subValue), value.length(), fontBold);
    cell.setCellValue(rts);

    wb.write(new FileOutputStream("BoldFile.xlsx"));
    
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always create the `RichTextString` using     `CreationHelper.createRichTextString(java.lang.String text)` where `CreationHelper` comes from `Workbook.getCreationHelper()`. So you can be sure, that the created `RichTextString` always is of same type as the workbook. For example `HSSFRichTextString` from a `HSSFCreationHelper`, `XSSFRichTextString` from a `XSSFCreationHelper` and `XSSFRichTextString` for streaming `SXSSF` from a `SXSSFCreationHelper`. When created using the constructors that is not always guaranteed.

But using `SXSSF` there is an issue when `SXSSFWorkbook` uses inline strings instead of a shared strings table. This is the default in `SXSSF` because inline strings are better usable in the streaming approach. But Apache POI fails to create rich text content in inline strings. It only creates rich text content in the shared strings table, which is the default in Excel.

So using `Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();` no rich text cell content can be created. One needs using `Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(), 100, false, true);` which tells to create a `SXSSFWorkbook` from a new empty `XSSFWorkbook`,  using the default `rowAccessWindowSize`  of  100, not to use gzip compression for temporary files and to use a shared strings table.

Following code will work for all kinds of `Workbook` and create rich text cell content.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelRichTextString {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx");
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xls");
  
  //Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx");
  Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(), 100, false, true); FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx");

  CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

  Font font = workbook.createFont(); // default font
  Font fontBold = workbook.createFont();
  fontBold.setBold(true);
  Font fontItalic  = workbook.createFont();
  fontItalic.setItalic(true);

  String text = "This is some sample content.";
  RichTextString richTextString = creationHelper.createRichTextString(text);
  String word = "some";
  int startIndex = text.indexOf(word);
  int endIndex = startIndex + word.length();
  richTextString.applyFont(startIndex, endIndex, fontBold);
  word = "sample";
  startIndex = text.indexOf(word);
  endIndex = startIndex + word.length();
  richTextString.applyFont(startIndex, endIndex, fontItalic);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(richTextString);

  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
  if (workbook instanceof SXSSFWorkbook) ((SXSSFWorkbook)workbook).dispose();
 }
}
```

Conclusion: Stop thinking `SXSSF` is the better `XSSF` because of using streaming approach to save memory usage. It is not. It has disadvantages of it's own. The structure of spreadsheet application files is nothing what is good to stream bulk data in.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But your solution is not working for me with following code snippets also. Please double check I am also checking.Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(), 100, false, true);

Comment: @Dipak Dutta: My code is complete and tested and works using current `apache poi 5.2.2`. It creates rich text content in `A1` of  `Sheet0` even if `SXSSF` is used.

Comment: Thanks it works. I had older version of poi jars. I updated and it worked. I will try tomorrow in my actual work and let you know if I face any challenge.

Comment: SXSSF rich text was only fixed in POI 5.2.2 - issue https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65943

Comment: I tested version 5.2.5 of poi, and the rich text color setting worked, but the bolding didn't work.

Comment: After in-depth research, I found that my problem was caused by using an older version of WPS, the specific version number is 11.8.2.10321, which cannot correctly recognize the `<b val="true"/>` tag, but can correctly recognize `<b />`

Comment: This is the code I used to solve my problem https://github.com/meiMingle/RichTextDemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/richtext/WPSXSSFRichTextString.java